# Why does it puts error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void' in arduino uno code?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

This code is for opening four leds when the switch is opened, and depending on the temperature there are two more leds opened or closed, one red and one green.

```
const int sensorPin = A0;   
type void setup(){   
  pinMode(2,INPUT);//the switch  
  for(int pinNumber>2 && pinNumber<7);//four leds   
  pinMode(pinNumber,OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);//green led  
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);//red led   
}  
type void loop(){  
  for(int pinNumber>2 && pinNumber<7);  
  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW){//if the switch is off the 4 leds are off  
  digitalWrite(pinNumber, LOW);  
  }  
  else{  
  digitalWrite(pinNumber, HIGH);//if the switch is open the 4 leds are opened  
  }  
  int sensorVal = analogRead(sensorPin);  
  float voltage = (sensorVal/1024.0);  
  float temperature= (voltage -0.5)*100;   
  if(temperature < 40){  
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);  
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);   
  }   
  else{   
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);   
  }    
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code. It's mainly for **you**.

Comment: `type void loop(){` is not valid c++ code, just say `void loop(){`.

Comment: `for(int pinNumber>2 && pinNumber<7);` is nowhere near correct. I suggest you return to your book and read a little about loops.

Answer (score 1):

**Code issues**
There are a number of problems in your code which would prevent it from compiling or working as you intend.

Firstly, as mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't have the word `type` in front of function signatures. For example, instead of `type void loop()` it should just be `void loop()`. That's what's causing the error message you mentioned. The compiler simply doesn't understand it.

The second major problem is your `for` loops. The correct syntax in C++ is this:

```
for ( init; condition; iter)
{
}
```

The `init` section is run once before the loop starts, and it's usually used to declare/initialise a counter variable. The `condition` is checked immediately before each iteration of the loop, and stops as soon as it equates to `false`. It's typically used to check the counter value. Finally, the `iter` section is executed at the end of each loop iteration, and is usually used to increment/advance the counter.

It's (usually) important not to have a semi-colon immediately after the `for` loop, otherwise your loop body is empty (i.e. it won't loop through anything). Either put a single statement after it, or multiple statements surrounded by curly braces `{ ... }`.

In your case, it looks like you want your `for` loop to go through values 3, 4, 5 and 6. To do that, you need to do something like this:

```
for (int pinNumber = 3; pinNumber < 7; ++pinNumber)
{
    // (loop body goes here)
}
```

That declares a loop counter called `pinNumber`, and starts it with the value 3. After each iteration of the loop, the counter goes up by one (`++pinNumber`). The loop stops when the counter reaches 7.

**Corrected code**
Putting all of that together, I think this code should work better:

```
const int sensorPin = A0;   
void setup()
{
    pinMode(2, INPUT);//the switch

    for (int pinNumber = 3; pinNumber < 7; ++pinNumber)
    {
        pinMode(pinNumber, OUTPUT);//four leds
    }

    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);//green led
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);//red led
}

void loop()
{
    for (int pinNumber = 3; pinNumber < 7; ++pinNumber)
    {        
        if (digitalRead(2) == LOW)
        {
            //if the switch is off the 4 leds are off
            digitalWrite(pinNumber, LOW);
        }
        else
        {
            //if the switch is open the 4 leds are opened
            digitalWrite(pinNumber, HIGH);
        }
    }

    int sensorVal = analogRead(sensorPin);
    float voltage = (sensorVal / 1024.0);
    float temperature = (voltage - 0.5) * 100;
    if (temperature < 40)
    {
        digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(7, LOW);
        digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    } 
}
```